# Linux mint 19.2 cannot get external monitor to work

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, multi-monitor

I am on an MSI GS63VR Stealth Pro and have just tried to connect an external monitor to my laptop via HDMI.

The monitor runs when i boot through windows (system is dual OS) and also runs of a raspberry pi I had lying around.

When I try to run it on my linux mint OS it is not recognised.

Driver manager has nvidia-390, nvidia-430 and nvidia-435 drivers.

I am fairly new to linux so anything that may seem straight forward to you may not be obvious to me, so any and all suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Wich version did you use ?  Cinnamon,MATE, XFCE  ?

Does the 'Display' (translated, in my french version it is 'Affichage')  setting show the monitor  ?
[image]

Comment: Cinnamon (or maybe its Tina now with updates?). The display GUI does not show the monitor.

Comment: (Small detail, Tina is the release, Cinnamon is the edition)  So it seems that the drivers does not recognize the hardware.  Did  you know wich  graphics card is used  ?

Comment: Following 'https://laptopmedia.com/laptop-specs/msi-gs63vr-7rf-stealth-pro/'   ,  there is a  'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060',  so start the 'Drivers' program, and install the recommended driver from Nvidia.  
Post another question or edit, explaining release and edition for specific help, I use MATE edition,  who is maybe different